# KeyDown removes input from my TextBox, how to stop this?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, textbox, keydown

I'm making a login form in which I want to press the *`Enter`* key and I get a `peroformedClick` on my login button intitled `BtnLogin`.

```
private void txtPassword_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        BtnLogin.PerformClick();
    }
}
```

The issue is that when I press *`Enter`* key I lose input on my password *`TextBox`* intitled `txtPassword` text box.

How to stop this from happening?

Comment: The code which do something with the `txtPassword` is not shown here. Can you add it?

Comment: Try `e.Handled = true` inside the `if`.

Comment: What do you have in the `BtnLogin.Click` event handler? Double check what is happening in there.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen that's all what I do with txtPassword in fact. But my `Enter` key makes the `BtnLogin` get clicked

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride didn't work..

Comment: @dr.null What needs to be done there exactly? It simply grabs input from database and logs in....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply use the following code without the loss of the password after "ENTER". The code is as follows:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
  {
    this.button1_Click(sender, e);
  }
}
```

But if I set the TextBox as a multi -line text, the password is lost after pressing "ENTER".(Actually the password is not lost, but it has been topped)

[image]

You need to click on the small triangle in the upper right corner of TextBox in the designer to cancel the "Multiline"

[image]

If this answer is not what you want, please provide a more complete code

Comment: No no, actually I edited my Enter key to actually click my  `btnLogin` button

Comment: actually you are right, I didn't notice because the button does its effect too. Thank you, this is a correct answer!